# Post html form triggering ajax request NO JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an old js code working fine for ajax requests WITHOUT JQuery:

```
function makeGetRequestTar(key) {
    http.open('GET', key, true);
    //assign a handler for the response
    http.onreadystatechange = processResponseTar;
    //actually send the request to the server
    http.send(null);
}

function processResponseTar() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

But now i want to:

1. Trigger the ajax request when submitting an html form
2. Pass the `'content'`  in `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML` as a variable.
3. Continue WITHOUT JQuery

So this is my js code now:

```
function makeGetRequestTar(fileTarget, htmlTarget) {

    http.open('GET', fileTarget, true);
    //assign a handler for the response
    http.onreadystatechange = processResponseTar(htmlTarget);
    //actually send the request to the server
    http.send(null);
}

function processResponseTar(htmlTarget) {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById(htmlTarget).innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

And here the html:

```
<div id="description-form">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="xxx" action="receiver.php" method="post" target="my-iframe">
        <textarea class="proposal" name="description" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" onclick="return makeGetRequestTar('doc/description.txt','description-preview')" value=" Save text " />
        <br>
        <iframe name="my-iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="description-preview" style="float:left">
    <?php include("doc/description.txt")?>
</div>
```

This code does not throw any error on the console. And the form is posted correctly via php.

But the ajax request is not working, why does it not work if there are no errors showing?

Comment: Is the fact that you've renamed your function `processResponse` to `processResponseTar` but haven't updated your call (`http.onreadystatechange = processResponse(htmlTarget);`) relevant?  Surely that would show an error in the console tho...

Comment: try to add `return false` in your `makeGetRequestTar` function.

Comment: @Alex the name of the function has been updated, i will change it here to avoid confusion thx

Comment: You're assigning the *result* of the function call `processResponse(...)` as a callback, rather than the *function itself*.

Comment: @Kenney not sure i understand.. in that case it shouldn't have worked in my old code right?

Comment: "Trigger the ajax request when submitting an html form" , so you just want an ajax request and not the form submitting and then page getting redirected , is that right?

Comment: i want both the form being submitted and the ajax request. But i avoid the page being redirected by posting the form into an iframe `'my-iframe'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old code

```
http.onreadystatechange = processResponseTar;
```

*assigns the callback function* `processResponseTar` to the `onreadystatechange` event property.

The new code

```
http.onreadystatechange = processResponse(htmlTarget);
```

*calls your callback* (note the `(..)`). You can't add custom parameters to that callback. One way to make `htmlTarget` accessible to your callback is this:

```
function makeGetRequestTar(fileTarget, htmlTarget) {
    http.open('GET', fileTarget, true);
    //assign a handler for the response
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        processResponseTar(htmlTarget);
    };
    //actually send the request to the server
    http.send(null);
}
```

Comment: What is happening then? Form not submitted, ajax not going through?

Comment: Sorry theres an error yes, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nullprocessResponse @ scripts.js:183http.onreadystatechange @ scripts.js:195`

Comment: That error is because i just pasted ur code, `processResponse(htmlTarget);` has to be changed for `processResponseTar(htmlTarget);` Now no error, but ajax call is not going through - form is submitted.

Comment: Ok now its working but its calling the previous data stored... like it first does the ajax request and then submits the form

Comment: I just tested it and yes, it works just fine. The way you set it up it will do the AJAX request asynchronously, so it *may* happen after the form submit. It is an odd design to do 2 requests like that - what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: People submit their data and i just want to show them what they have submitted without having to refresh the page cuz there are several forms in the page

Comment: Then you have 4 options. 1) use synchronous ajax (`http.open('GET', uri, false)` -  note the false); that way the submit will only happen after the ajax is done. 2) use only ajax and do not submit the form; 3) do not use ajax and submit the form to the iframe. 4) do the ajax call after the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are *executing* the function `processReponse` here:

```
http.onreadystatechange = processResponse(htmlTarget);
```

and assigning the RESULT of that function (which in this case is `undefined`) to `http.onreadystatechange`.

Now, when the readystate changes, `XMLHttpRequest` attempts to call `onreadystatechange` which is now `undefined`, so nothing happens.

Try this:

```
function processResponseTar(htmlTarget) {
    return function () {
        if(http.readyState == 4){
            var response = http.responseText;
            document.getElementById(htmlTarget).innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you are still assigning the result of the function to `http.onreadystatechange`, but this time it is a callable function instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Kenney's answer has worked, i guess yours is correct too, i just tried both and didn't work at the first go, so i kept trying here and there and his code was the first to  show results although you answered first...

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `http` is undefined, you need to define that. And second, you're calling `processResponse` function but function name is `processResponseTar`.

**Edited:**

```
<script>
    var http;
    function makeGetRequestTar(fileTarget, htmlTarget) {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            http=new XMLHttpRequest();    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        }else{
            http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   // code for IE6, IE5
        }
        http.open('GET', fileTarget, true);
        //assign a handler for the response
        http.onreadystatechange = processResponseTar(htmlTarget);
        //actually send the request to the server
        http.send(null);
    }

    function processResponseTar(htmlTarget) {
        return function () {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status==200){
                var response = http.responseText;
                document.getElementById(htmlTarget).innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This will also fail, for the reason outlined in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33854922/1136527).  I think it's also safe to say that OP has setup `http` variable before this codeblock.